# Inheritance vs. Strategy Pattern

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, polymorphism, strategy-pattern

I'm learning about programming patterns and for our final assignment we were asked to build an "online store".

I was thinking about how to model the `User` which can either be `Admin` or `Customer`.

I thought about the Strategy pattern to model each individual `User` with their particular behaviors.

They don't share any behaviors so far, so the `Admin` can't `addToCart` and `Customer` can't `registerNewProduct`.

**However, they could share behaviors / methods as the system evolves!**

Furthermore, the `User` won't change it's type in run-time. I.e., once you log in as Customer, you can't log back in as Admin.

Even if they shared behaviors such as `seeProductList`, this could be achieved with good ol' inheritance, right?

Should I use Strategy, Inheritance or would you recommend another pattern?

If you need more information, please let me know! :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've tumbled into the `puzzle` of **patterns**.

Actually there is no obvious reason to use `Strategy` here. Let's first see what's the most outstanding feature of [`Strategy`](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy).

> Strategy is a behavioral design pattern that lets you define a family of algorithms, encapsulate each one, and make them **interchangeable**. Strategy lets the algorithm vary independently from the clients that use it.

As I see it, if you wanna use different `methods/algorithms` to solve the same problem, you would use `Strategy`.

A demo would be `parse(File file)` and there are several methods to parse the file for different scenarios.

#### Strategy - 1:

```
parseInParallel(File file) // when in single-user system;
```

#### Strategy - 2:

```
parseSequatially(File file) // multi-user system;
```

You see, they're achieving the same target but use different methods.

In your case, I would like to recommend `inheritance` since there are lots of common features between *Customer* and *Admin*, which might include:

1. name;
2. age;
3. email;
4. gender/sex;
5. address;
6. telephone;
7. and more other related to person...

But as you already mentioned, a lot of methods are different. So you can add them separately in the `subclass` so basically you will have `Person`, `Customer` and `Admin`.

`Person` has the most basic information and method, `Customer` has the methods and new fields related to customers and `Admin` similarly.